# How can I set codeigniter session userdata with using next.js url fetch?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, next.js

Hello Im trying to create an common login page. If he/she logs in from one, he/she will be logged in from the others. Everything works expect setting session userdata. Im fetching function like this with next.js:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const req = await fetch('domain/api_test', 
    { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}, body: JSON.stringify({ email: email,password:password })})
    const newData = await req.json();
   console.log(newData);
   
  };
```

and getting user in codeigniter like :

```
function api_test(){
      
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      header('access-control-allow-origin: *');
      header('SameSite=None;');
      $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    

        $this->db->where('email',$obj['email']);
        $this->db->where('password',$obj['password']);
        $user = $this->db->get('admin')->row();
        if(!empty($user)){
       
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);

      
        
       
        echo json_encode($user);
      }else{
        echo json_encode(false);

      }
   
    }
```

but  `$this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);` part not works. How can I set it? I tried to put `ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');` and tried to change `$config['cookie_path'] = '/; SameSite=None';` in config and didnt work.

Comment: it should set session on request, its just simple ajax request.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: when you are setting session try to check on next page with $this->session->userdata('user'); to session is set or not.

Comment: not setting at all